# How to find out what country a Starcraft user is from by his battle ID and username?

Tags: starcraft-2

I was just wondering if anyone knew how to find a users country in starcraft 2. It is easy to get their battle tag. Besides asking the user.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no way to know the country of another player in battle.net

Answer (score 1):

I don't think so. You can sign onto any of the regions through the client, so it's practically impossible to determine for certain which country a user is from let alone the region.

Comment: I don't think so as well. It would be so nice to have a friend who works at Blizzard who can answer so may questions about Blizzard games. Especially about sc2's ladder.